# If Greece defaults, can it still stay with the euro?

Tags: exchange-rates, international-economics

Should Greece default, a forced conversion from euros to drachmas will be a further catastrophe to Greek economy as the drachma will quickly collapse. However, if Greece leaves the Eurozone, but keeps the Euro as a national currency (at least for a year), its value will be kept stable because of the implicit trust in the euro.

There already are precedents of countries using the euro without being members of the Eurozone (Montenegro, Kosovo, Monaco, etc.). Is that possible for Greece?

Comment: Why will the drachma quickly collapse?

Comment: And who is forcing a conversion to drachma?

Comment: @Lumi It would collapse just like any currency (from economically weaker countries) did that was bound to the US Dollar after the fixed exchange range was dropped. The question that I wonder is why that should be a bad thing. Naturally, devaluing the Greek currency would help Greek products to become competitive in the international market.

Comment: I feel this question is slightly off topic here. Whether Greece is legally allowed to stay in the Euro zone after defaulting is a law question.

Comment: @FooBar it's sloppy to assume that it would collapse automatically. Right now if they did a 1:1 conversion with the euro, it would probably rise, there's so little asset cash left in their banking system. The reason the US linked currencies collapse is that they over-expand their banking system relative to the dollar. That was what preceded the current crisis in Greece, but its' now what's happening now.

Comment: Echoing @FooBar, is this a legal question on the relationship between credit default and EMU membership? If it isn't a law question what do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

The Greek banks will not be able to get any Euro to give out, if the IMF and the EU cuts of all the loans to Greece.   Therefore if Greeces remains in the Euro, there will be no banking system in Greece.

Answer (score -2):

What is the point in staying Euro, if Greece defaults in its debt. If they default, they want to devalue the salary of the employees. If they still stay in Euro, they need to pay same salary in Euros to all their employees. Where will they get the Euros to pay those. The market to Greece will be closed more than now, there will be no emergency assistance from ECB.

Comment: This answers the question whether it *should* leave the Euro zone. OP asked the question whether it *can*.